# How to draw vertical line on axes in Matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, drawing, matlab-guide, axes

I have a Matlab GUI with 3 axes components. Their tags are `predicted_ax`, `cost_ax` and `error_ax`. I want to draw vertical line on particular position on the first axes component (the one with tag `predicted_ax`). How do I do that?

I tried this code:

```
ylim = get(handles.predicted_ax, 'ylim');
line([linePos, linePos], ylim);
```

But it draws the line on different axes (the ones with tag `error_ax`)! I'm sure I did not confuse tags or axes components. In the fact another test

```
ylim = get(handles.cost_ax, 'ylim');
line([linePos, linePos], ylim);
```

gives exactly the same result: the line is drawn on the last axes component with tag `error_ax`. So how do I draw the line on the right axes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the 'parent' property of the line, as by default it will always be the current axis:

```
h = line([linePos, linePos], ylim);
set(h, 'parent', handles.predicted_ax);
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  Every line has a parent axes.  If you don't supply the line() function with an axes handle it will attach the line to the "current" axes by default.  That is why axes(handles.predicted_ax) works.  It makes predicted_ax the current axes and so any line you create afterwards will have it as a default parent. However, I feel it is much clearer to just set the 'Parent' property of the line to the axes you want to attach it to.  In general it is never a good idea to rely on using the current axes (gca) or current figure (gcf) when you have clearer options available.

Comment: As a side note.  You can do this all in one call like this: `line([linePos, linePos], ylim, 'Parent', handles.predicted_ax)`

Comment: @cholland It would be best answer if it worked. But it does not.

Comment: @cholland However it does work if I do I as you suggested - create line and set parent in one call.

Comment: His is mostly correct, well I should say the idea is correct.  The only thing he is missing is the handles.predicted_ax part. This is what he meant to say: `h = line([linePos, linePos], ylim);
set(h, 'parent', handles.predicted_ax)`;

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `axes` command to set the current axis on which the line will be drawn.  Try `axes(handles.predicted_ax);` prior to your `line` command.

(Getting the `ylim` value for the axis apparently does not make it current.)